# Is it possible that Rails form helper get block as submit button?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms

I want to use block as submit button in Rails. The normal usage is like this.

```
<%= form_tag("sample_path", method: "post") do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag(:post_id, "5") %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

But what I want to do is below.

```
<%= form_tag("sample_path", method: "post") do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag(:post_id, "5") %>
  <div>
    <div>foo</div>
    <div>bar</div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I want to use block as submit button. But Rails doesn't recognize this as submit button.

Do anyone know how to realize this? Thanks.

Comment: I don't get your question. What is sampleBlock ?

Comment: I edited the part you mentioned. I meant just a block with plain text. sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4):

You have a couple of options:

1) You can use [button_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/button_tag) for that:

```
<%= button_tag(type: 'submit') do %>
  <div>foo</div>
  <div>bar</div>
<% end %>
```

2) Adding [onclick](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) js event:

```
<div onclick="$('#form-id').submit();">
  <div>foo</div>
  <div>bar</div>
</div>
```

3) Bind an event handler to the "[click](https://api.jquery.com/click/)" JavaScript event:

```
$('#your-div').click(function() {
  $('#form-id').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [#submit_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/submit_tag) just renders a regular HTML input tag.

```
submit_tag "Search"
# => <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Search" />
```

Using only HTML you can submit a form using either `<button type='submit'>` or `<input type='submit'>` tags. If you want to submit the form using a `<div>`, you can put a `onclick` handler on the element you want to use to submit the form.

```
<%= form_tag("sample_path", method: "post") do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag(:post_id, "5") %>
  <div onclick="$('#your_form_id_here')[0].submit();>
    <div>foo</div>
    <div>bar</div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But I suggest setting the `onclick` event handler in the `.js` file for that particular view. It keeps code more organised.